# requires_grad relation to leaf nodes

Tags: pytorch

From the [docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pytorch-zh/latest/pytorch-zh.pdf://):

> requires_grad – Boolean indicating whether the Variable has been
>   created by a subgraph containing any Variable, that requires it.  Can
>   be changed only on leaf Variables

1. What does it mean by leaf nodes here? Are leaf nodes only the input nodes?
2. If it can be only changed at the leaf nodes, how can I freeze layers then?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Leaf nodes of a graph are those nodes (i.e. `Variables`) that were not computed directly from other nodes in the graph. For example:

   ```
   import torch
   from torch.autograd import Variable

   A = Variable(torch.randn(10,10)) # this is a leaf node
   B = 2 * A # this is not a leaf node
   w = Variable(torch.randn(10,10)) # this is a leaf node
   C = A.mm(w) # this is not a leaf node
   ```

   If a leaf node `requires_grad`, all subsequent nodes computed from it will automatically also `require_grad`. Else, you could not apply the chain rule to calculate the gradient of the leaf node which `requires_grad`. This is the reason why `requires_grad` can only be set for leaf nodes: For all others, it can be smartly inferred and is in fact determined by the settings of the leaf nodes used for computing these other variables.
2. Note that in a typical neural network, **all parameters are leaf nodes.** They are not computed from any other `Variables` in the network. Hence, freezing layers using `requires_grad`is simple. Here, is an example taken from the PyTorch docs:

   ```
   model = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
   for param in model.parameters():
       param.requires_grad = False

   # Replace the last fully-connected layer
   # Parameters of newly constructed modules have requires_grad=True by default
   model.fc = nn.Linear(512, 100)

   # Optimize only the classifier
   optimizer = optim.SGD(model.fc.parameters(), lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9)
   ```

   Even though, what you really do is freezing the entire gradient computation (which is what you should be doing as it avoids unnecessary computation). Technically, you could leave the `requires_grad` flag on, and only define your optimizer for a subset of the parameters that you would like to learn.

Comment: The fact that all parameters of a layer are leaf nodes and require grad are the reason that the output of custom Network requires grad. Is it true?

Comment: I can think of one counterexample. Weight normalization requires your variables to be initialized based on data. What is the current behavior in PyTorch regarding this?